# Not able to extract file extensions from line of file

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I run the below program, I dont get the expected output.

```
import os
import re

f = open('outputFile','w')


#flag set to 1 when we are processing the required diffs
diff_flag=0   #Initialized to 0 in beginning

#with open('Diff_output.txt') as fp:
with open('testFile') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if re.match('diff --git',line):
                #fileExtension = os.path.splitext(line)[1]
                words=line.split(".")   
                diff_flag=0
#               print fileExtension
                str=".rtf"      

                print words[-1]

                if words[-1] != "rtf":
                        print "Not a text file.."       
                        diff_flag = 1
                        f.write(line)
                        print "writing -> " + line      

        elif diff_flag == 1:
                f.write(line)
        else:
                continue
```

I get the output as below:

```
python read.py 
rtf

Not a text file..
writing -> diff --git a/archived-output/NEW/action-core[best].rtf b/archived-output/NEW/action-core[best].rtf
```

It is a text file and the if condition should evaluate to false. When I print words[-1] or fileExtension , I get the right extension. But then I am not able to understand why this condition is failing. Is it that there is something wrong with the content of these two variables because of which the condition is evaluating to true ( not equals) . I am trying to read the file line by line and extract extension of filenames here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate a file like you are doing, the lines will include the newline "\n", what you should do is either:

```
words = line.strip().split(".").
```

or

```
if words[-1].strip() != "rtf":
```

But what I'd do if I were you is:

```
if line.strip().endswith(".rtf"):
```

Instead of splitting the line.

BTW, the proof of the newline is your output:

```
rtf
 <-- empty line here.
```

Answer (score 1):

2 point:

1.[`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) tries to match the pattern from the beginning the line If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead. (see also [search() vs. match()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match))

2.`words=line.split(".")` doesn't give you the list of words be cause it will contain whitespaces like `\n` at the trailing or leading of the file you need to first `strip` your lines :

```
words=line.strip().split(".")
```